# How to Integrate a Script with Thunkable Web API and Create a Public API in Flask Using Playwright?

Tags: python, flask, playwright, thunkable

I have a Python script, as shown below, that I'd like to connect to Thunkable and use it to create a public API in Flask. I am new to working with APIs and would appreciate guidance on the process.

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
```

What I've Tried:

I have developed the script for web scraping using Playwright, but I'm unsure how to proceed with integrating it into Thunkable and creating a public API in Flask. I need help with the overall process, including the steps and best practices for making this integration and API creation possible. I've been researching on what flask is and ngork to create a public api that invokes my scripts

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

def saved_auth(playwright):
    browser = playwright.chromium.launch_persistent_context(headless=False, user_data_dir="", slow_mo=3000)
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto('https://brightspace.uri.edu')

    target_url = 'https://brightspace.uri.edu/d2l/home'

    while page.url != target_url:
        page.wait_for_url(target_url, timeout=0)  # Check the URL without waiting

    auth = browser.storage_state(path="auth.json")
    page.close()
    browser.close()
    return auth

def scrape_with_saved_auth(playwright, auth):
    browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=True, slow_mo=1000)
    context = browser.new_context(storage_state=auth)
    page = context.new_page()
    page.goto('https://brightspace.uri.edu')

    page.get_by_role("navigation").get_by_role("link", name="Calendar").click()
    page.get_by_role("button", name="Subscribe").click()

    iframe_locator = page.wait_for_selector('iframe[name^="d2l_c_"]', timeout=20000)
    iframe = iframe_locator.content_frame()

    dynamic_selector = '[class^="d2l_1_7_"]'  # Replace with the common part of the dynamic class

    element_selector = iframe.wait_for_selector(dynamic_selector, timeout=20000)

    link_element = element_selector.query_selector('.d2l-textblock')

    if link_element:
        link_text = link_element.inner_text()
        return link_text
    else:
        return 'Link element not found'


with sync_playwright() as playwright:
    auth = saved_auth(playwright)
    link_text = scrape_with_saved_auth(playwright, auth)
    print(link_text)
```